# Return the row number of the string value in a numeric column?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to convert a column to numeric, If most of the values in a column are numeric but some contain string values, then the function should return the row no of the columns which contain string values.
my dataset:

```
received
11
12
0
-340
2
9
1
aa
nn
qbb
```

expected output: row no :8,9,10 contains string values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need filter by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for return `NaN`s for non numeric with `isnull`:

```
i = df.index[pd.to_numeric(df['received'], errors='coerce').isnull()]
print (i)
Int64Index([7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')
```

python count from `0`, so if need change it from count from `1`:

```
i = df.index[pd.to_numeric(df['received'], errors='coerce').isnull()] + 1
print (i)
Int64Index([8, 9, 10], dtype='int64')
```

For dictionary use:

```
d = df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['received'], errors='coerce').isnull(), 'received'].to_dict()
print (d)
{8: 'nn', 9: 'qbb', 7: 'aa'}
```

Comment: can I get the row no with the value, like {8:"aa",9:"nn"} ?

Comment: it's giving a blank dictionary

Comment: @Sidhartha - I think it means there are no string values, only numeric. What return `df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['received'], errors='coerce').isnull()]` ?